# Four consecutive integers with squarefree part < n^(1/2)

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $sfp(n)=core(n)$ be the squarefree part of $n$.

Are there infinitely many integers with 
$$sfp(n),sfp(n+1),sfp(n+2),sfp(n+3) < n^{\frac12}$$?

For three integers this is OEIS A260212 which gives only one quadruple
up to $10^{12}$.

Three integers with $sfp < n^{1/3}$ is A254625 and it gives infinite
family.

Solution might come from polynomial identities. Three of the integers
are of the form $(a_i x + b_i)^2 (c_i x^2 + d_i x + e_i)$ and the fourth is of
form $(A x^2 + B x + C) (E x^2 + F x + G)$ and then make the quadratic
factor constant time square. Couldn't find low hanging fruit
identities.

abc allows it, but it is abc near miss.